# How to run an animation in loop

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm shaking a widget using the below code, but the effect is once,

how do I keep it running in a loop at timed intervals. I believe it can be done by changing the key but it's a final and can't be changed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@immutable
class ShakeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Duration duration;
  final double deltaX;
  final Widget child;
  final Curve curve;

  const ShakeWidget({
    Key key,
    this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    this.deltaX = 20,
    this.curve = Curves.bounceOut,
    this.child,
  }) : super(key: key);

  /// convert 0-1 to 0-1-0
  double shake(double animation) =>
      2 * (0.5 - (0.5 - curve.transform(animation)).abs());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
      key: key,
      tween: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
      duration: duration,
      builder: (context, animation, child) => Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(deltaX * shake(animation), 0),
        child: child,
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You need to use AnimationController
And call repeat when the controller is completed

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ShakeWidget(
          child: Text('Hello world'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShakeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShakeWidget({
    super.key,
    this.duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    this.deltaX = 20,
    this.curve = Curves.bounceOut,
    required this.child,
  });

  final Duration duration;
  final double deltaX;
  final Widget child;
  final Curve curve;

  @override
  State<ShakeWidget> createState() => _ShakeWidgetState();
}

class _ShakeWidgetState extends State<ShakeWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      duration: widget.duration,
      vsync: this,
    )
      ..forward()
      ..addListener(() {
        if (controller.isCompleted) {
          controller.repeat();
        }
      });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  /// convert 0-1 to 0-1-0
  double shake(double value) =>
      2 * (0.5 - (0.5 - widget.curve.transform(value)).abs());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: controller,
      builder: (context, child) => Transform.translate(
        offset: Offset(widget.deltaX * shake(controller.value), 0),
        child: child,
      ),
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how can we use this for vertically animation?

Comment: I think you need a "late AnimationController" these days because null-safety.

Comment: We can also use `..repeat(reverse: true)` instead of `..forward().addListener(...)`.

Answer (score 7):

Use an AnimationController, like so:

```
AnimationController(
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  vsync: this,
)..repeat();
```

Answer (score 3):

The [simple_animations](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_animations/changelog) package comes with the LoopAnimation widget which is meant for exactly this. This also means you don't have to create an AnimationController so the code's a lot cleaner.

```
LoopAnimation(
      builder: (context, child, double value) {
        return Transform.rotate(
          angle: pi * value,
          child: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
        );
      },
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 2),

    );
```

If you want to run an animation forward and backward continuously to get a yo-yo effect, you can use the MirrorAnimation widget instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the repeating animation sample, from `start → end` then from `end ← start`

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: widget.duration);
    _animation = widget.tween.animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeIn));
    _animationController.forward();
    // The looping is done via listener.
    _animationController.addListener(() {
        if (_animationController.isCompleted) {
          _animationController.reverse();
        }
        if(_animationController.isDismissed){
          _animationController.forward();
        }
    });
  }
```

Don't forget to call `_animationController.dispose()` in the state's `dispose()` method.